# Azure Service Bus Session Ordering

Tags: azureservicebus

Let's say we have the following messages which are all part of the same Session and were placed onto the Topic in alphabetical order.

A, B, C, D

The session receiver will pick up and process message A first before moving onto B.

But what happens if message A cannot be processed. Will the receiver automatically move onto B? Or will it still respect the sequencing?

Comment: how do you implement a session receiver? i'd like to receieve all messages for a specific session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer in [Message sessions: first in, first out (FIFO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions):

> The session lock held by the session receiver is an umbrella for the message locks used by the peek-lock settlement mode. A receiver cannot have two messages concurrently "in flight," but the messages must be processed in order. **A new message can only be obtained when the prior message has been completed or dead-lettered**. Abandoning a message causes the same message to be served again with the next receive operation.

In short this means that when, in your example, message A is dead-lettered because it exceeds MaxDeliveryCount, message B will be processed.